# How do I use jQuery positioning to put a child div on the top right corner of it's parent on the inside

Tags: jquery

here is what I have and it's not working:

```
$(".child").position({
    of: $(".child").parent(),
    my: "top right",
    at: "top right"
});
```

And here is what the DOM look like:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
        sup
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What API are you using ? [jquery's position doesn't seem to accept parameters](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth you'd use Javascript (let alone jquery) to do this is beyond me. **Basic** CSS will do the trick.

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use css?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAFZK/)

```
.child {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   float: right;
}
```